# How an AJAX application informs client the events fired in server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

How an AJAX application like those written in ASP.NET AJAX informs client the events fired in server? I meant some application like Gmail. Gmail tells the client whenever a new email has been arrived. I'm very interested how is done in ASP.NET AJAX using UpdatePanel. I know UpdatePanel has a Triggers property, but it works only with Controls events not events of my own classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax applications check server state continously to achieve this effect. They always work as clients and cannot receive requests from server.

Comment: Thanks for reply but does it affect performance and band width consumption because of continuous connection to server?

Comment: To be precise, you are not continously connected to the server (connection is closed after every request) but you have to make requests to the server continously (e.g. every 10 seconds). I don't think there could be any performance penalty on bandwidth, since ajax messages are usually very small (response usually is in xml and is about a few kilobytes long). The only problem is the polling model you are using - you're polling even though there could be no new messages. If you're looking for duplex communication check e.g. java applets.

Answer (score 0):

When an application uses AJAX, a new layer is added to the communication model. In the classic web application, communication between the client (the browser) and the web server were performed directly, using HTTP requests.

When the visitor requests a page, the server will send the full HTML and CSS code at once. After the visitor fills in a form and submits it, the server processes the information and rebuilds the page. It then sends the full page back to the client. And so on.

When using AJAX, the page is loaded entirely only once, the first time it is requested. Besides the HTML and CSS code that make up the page, some JavaScript files are also downloaded: the AJAX engine. All requests for data to the sever will then be sent as JavaScript calls to this engine. The AJAX engine then requests information from the web server asynchronously. Thus, only small page bits are requested and sent to the browser, as they are needed by the user. The engine then displays the information without reloading the entire page. This leads to a much more responsive interface, because only the necessary information is passed between the client and server, not the whole page. This produces the feeling that information is displayed immediately, which brings web applications closer to their desktop relatives.

To better illustrate the communication between the client (browser) and the remote server, as well as the differences between the classic and the AJAX-powered applications, take a look at the diagram below:

AJAX communication model diagram
Illustration 1: Classic and AJAX communication models
[image]
<sub>(source: [interaktonline.com](http://www.interaktonline.com/img/art/AJAX/ajax_comm_model_gif.gif?0.33986484845155046))</sub>

At the heart of the AJAX method of communicating with the server lies the AJAX engine. This is nothing more than some JavaScript code that instantiates and uses the XMLHttpRequest object. This is a JavaScript object that allows sending, receiving and processing HTTP requests to and from the server without refreshing the entire page.

In AJAX-powered applications, HTTP requests for data can be made completely in the background, without the user experiencing any interruptions. This means the user can continue working and using the application, while the necessary page sections are received from the server. The XMLHttpRequest object was implemented as an ActiveX object in Internet Explorer, and has later become a native JavaScript object in most modern browsers (FireFox, Safari).

Although adding an extra layer to any kind of model should add to the response time, this is an exception. Through the use of this new layer – the AJAX engine – response time shortens and the user interface seems much more connected to the application logic. Moreover, the user no longer has to wait around for the page to load.